# Rails tinymce gem and tinymce-rails-imageupload gem broken image on edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, imagemagick, paperclip

I have successfully setup the tinymce gem and the tinymce-rails-imageupload gem (using paperclip to handle image storing) and they are working well together however when I go to edit a page I get a broken image inside the tinymce editor. The server log shows the following error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pages/system/images/files/000/000/002/original/test.jpg"):
```

The image renders fine inside the tinymce editor when I create a new page and upload it initially and also displays fine on the show action for the page but for some reason on the edit action it sticks the controller '/pages/' into the file path. The images actual location is:

```
system/images/files/000/000/002/original/test.jpg?1418950559
```

How do I set the route for the image so it works in the edit action for pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after getting some food I think I have identified the issue.

You stated that it works fine on the "Show" action (meaning the TinyMCE editor is not involved at that point) and it also works on the "Create" action (so the initial creation process works to include it in the TinyMCE) however it does not work in the Edit action.

I think you simply need to change one setting on the Javascript for TinyMCE to indicate that relative urls *are* being used.  So undo what I told you previously, and then for the tinyMCE javascript:

`$("[rel=tinymce]").tinymce({
theme: "modern",
...
relative_urls: false
...`

As it turns out, it was required to set the relative_URLs setting on tinyMCE configuration to false.

Comment: This gives me: `ERROR bad URI `/pages/[object%20Object]'.` How do I remove the controller 'pages' from the path?

Comment: Thanks for your time. It helped even if it didn't fix it. I will figure it out.

Comment: so if the following doesn't do it, then I'd say the next thing to look into would be changing the paperclip URL so that it includes /pages...

Try url: URI.join(request.protocol, request.host_with_port, image.file.url)

Comment: So your edited answer was so so close... relative urls are automatically set to `true` in tinymce so I actually had to set them to `false`. I just had to override the global options with the following where I included tinymce in my view.

    `<%= tinymce :relative_urls => false %>`

Please update your answer with this info so I can accept it as correct.